# UI Elements Missing Text After Segue When Called Asynchronously

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I'm faced with an interesting dilemma today in building my network analysis application for a college class. Calling `performSegue` from an asynchronous `DispatchQueue` is making the text of some of the UI in the destination view controller blank. Buttons, labels, etc. All just as though they had their text properties set to empty strings.

I'll explain further.

I've got a custom Swift class, called `Globals`, which is used to house (obviously) global variables that need to be read and written application-wide.

I've got a `UIViewController` that acts as a loading screen for my application.

I've got a `UIViewController` that loads at the completion of that loading screen.

I have a `URLSession` running in a separate Swift class that gets called by the loading screen view controller. Its purpose is to download a small file of known size and, by measuring the time it took to download it, deliver a speed estimate. Here's that function:

```
func testSpeed() {

    Globals.shared.dlStartTime = Date()

    if Globals.shared.currentSSID == "" {
        Globals.shared.bandwidth = 0
        Globals.shared.DownComplete = true
    } else {

        let url = URL(string: "[EXAMPLE]")
        let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        let task = session.downloadTask(with: url!)

        task.resume()
    }
}

public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

    Globals.shared.dlFileSize = (Double(totalBytesExpectedToWrite) * 8) / 1000

    let progress = (Double(totalBytesWritten) / Double(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)) * 100.0

    Globals.shared.dlprogress = Int(progress)
}

public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {

    let elapsed = Double( Date().timeIntervalSince(Globals.shared.dlStartTime))
    Globals.shared.bandwidth = Int(Globals.shared.dlFileSize / elapsed)
    Globals.shared.DownComplete = true
    Globals.shared.dataUse! += (Globals.shared.dlFileSize! / 8000)
}
```

As you can see, the `URLSession` uses the delegates `URLSessionDelegate` and `URLSessionDownloadDelegate` to pass the download progress to the loading screen, which lets the user know how things are going.

As you can also see, there is a global Boolean variable, `DownComplete`, which lets the rest of the application know when the process is finished.

Back to the loading screen. There's a completion label called `progressLabel` along with a custom radial progress view called `MainProgress`. Here's the code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    [...]

    Networking().testSpeed()
    updateProgress()
}

func updateProgress() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        while Globals.shared.DownComplete == false {
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                self.progressLabel.text = String(Globals.shared.dlprogress) + "%"
                self.MainProgress.animate(fromAngle: self.MainProgress.angle, toAngle: Double(Globals.shared.dlprogress)
            }
        }
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoadCompleteSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

The idea is to run a while loop which waits until the process is complete before loading the next view controller.

But to not block the main thread, the while loop has to be run asynchronously.

...But to update the UI correctly, those calls have to be made in a synchronous block.

......But to not skip the process entirely, the `performSegue` has to be done in the same thread as the while loop. And I think that's what's causing my problem.

I've got a screenshot of the next view controller below, where I've outlined areas where there *should* be text in red boxes. Because what baffles me is that it doesn't affect *all* the UI elements, just a few.

[Screenshot: Missing Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4S1Q.png)

**EDIT:**

I know the code isn't the cleanest, but this is my "testgrounds" Git branch. Bear with me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to perform the segue on the main queue. If you dispatch it after the while loop runs, it should work fine. Try updating your `updateProgress()` function to the following:

```
func updateProgress() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        while Globals.shared.DownComplete == false {
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                self.progressLabel.text = String(Globals.shared.dlprogress) + "%"
                self.MainProgress.animate(fromAngle: self.MainProgress.angle, toAngle: Double(Globals.shared.dlprogress)
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoadCompleteSegue", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I wish I had known it was that simple. You're a scholar and a saint, sir.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it in a really bad way. You could just use NSNotificatioCenter

In your viewDidLoad I'd observe these events:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(processFinished), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ProcessFinished"), object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ProcessUpdating), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ProcessUpdating"), object: nil)
```

and in your corresponding delegates I'd put this:

```
// complete event
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ProcessFinished"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)

// progress event
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ProcessUpdating"), object: nil, userInfo: ["progress" : 11])
```

Then you can handle your events with:

```
    func processFinished(notification: Notification) {
        // perform yout segue
        print("processFinished")

    }

    func ProcessUpdating(notification: Notification) {
        // update UI
        let progress = notification.userInfo!["progress"] as! Int
        print("progress: \(progress)")
    }
```

Comment: That's much smarter than anything I could've come up with. To be honest, I'm no expert with Swift or mobile development in general. I've never heard of NSNC. Like I said, this is really just for a class. But I have enough time that I'll probably try to re-implement it that way for better documentation.